# import file not showing to import

Tags: java

whenever run my class show this types of error in console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    ApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: How do you run your application? Do you run it in an IDE? Gradle? Maven? How are your dependencies managed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.